# Only one software recommandation per answer?

Tags: discussion

I answered a [software rec question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/30531/16275) by providing not just one recommandation but several softwares meeting or approaching the OP's criteria, divided into different categories depending on the final purpose (which was not described by OP).

Someone commented that it would be better to provide each recommendation as a separate answer, in order to vote for a particular software and not for the answer globally.

However, having one software per answer would prevent the possibility to provide some "big picture" descriptions such as the categories I wrote.

What is the preferred way to post software recommandation answers? One recommandation per answer? Or are softwares reviews acceptable as well? (given these reviews include personal experience of course).

Comment: This question is a duplicate of [What to do when an answer contains several suggestions?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/55/133), the rationale for this is explained [here](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/388/133)

Comment: Indeed this is discussed elsewhere, and is a duplicate. But as far as I can see, it's [still in debate](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/387/16275). So if nothing else, my answer on softwarerecs may serve as yet another example...

Comment: FYI, a more recent discussion about this is [*Should I flag answers that contain multiple, independent solutions?*](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2399/60).

Comment: While it may appear to be still in debate (note: the score is 4:1 in favor of one recommendation), we still do not want **exact** duplicate questions which is what this appears to be.

Comment: @Tom I assessed the fact that my question was a duplicate, and validated it myself... No debate on this, but about one/multiple recommendations, you based your 4:1 on [this post](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/55/what-to-do-when-an-answer-contains-several-suggestions), which has less votes than [this one](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/356/what-is-required-for-an-answer-to-be-high-quality/387#387), which has 34 votes (in favor of one rec) vs 20 votes (in favor of multiple recs). You seem to be advocating rather than informing on this point.

Comment: @gaborous I went purely off the score of each answer and currently it's 4:1 - saying that **does not** mean I'm advocating for a certain answer, I'm simply presenting a fact. To advocate means that I would have to **publicly support or recommend** one answer over another, which I have not done here.

Comment: @Tom You have done so here by skewing *facts*. If you take all answers from both questions as you say, you get a total of `(16+3+9)/((16+3+9)+(4+2+20)) = 52%` in favor of one rec. I am of course not accounting the questions vote, since we cannot know if people voted for the question or for the proposition inside the question (which should be put in a separate answer obviously). The only way to validate your 4:1 claim is by chosing the first two answers of the 1st question, so that's clearly biased. Conclusion: no consensus obviously, contrary to what you're claiming.